# Video recording not working in webview Android in Nougat 7.1 android

Tags: android, webview, android-camera, chromium, android-7.1-nougat

android.webkit.resource.video_capture permission in Android webview is not allowing javascript to use the camera even after overriding onPermissionRequest in webchromeclient and calling request.grant(request.getResources()); inside it.

The code works till Android 7.0 but doesn't work in Android 7.1. The console outputs [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(178)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported. on Android 7.1

Nougat version.

I have declared the permission in manifest and implemented the runtime permission for Android 6.0 and above.

Comment: Did you get any solution?